# Injecting dependency in controller (not as argument)

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-bootstrap

I want to use controller in modal (ui.bootstrap) and as normal view (without modal).
Controller is used for adding things - as normal view and in modal.

To know if controller is used by modal or normal view I'm using resolve attr in modal:

```
$modal.open({
    resolve: {
        inModal: function() {
            return true;
        }
    }
    //other
})
```

Problem is that to use it I need to inject it into controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope, inModal) {
    $scope.inModal = inModal;
}
```

But this depency isn't available in normal view.
Can I inject `inModal` in controller if it is available?

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    //$scope.inModal = inject inModal if it is available
}
```

Comment: you can try to use $injector but I don't sure it will get an error when you don't have this dependency or not

Comment: To be honest: The controller shouldn't know if it works in a modal or not.

Comment: I don't know how to do it `$injector.get("serviceName")` ?

Comment: zeroflagL: Why not? I want to hide header and use func on modal resolve

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resolve, you can pass a scope to your $modal options:

```
   $scope.inModal = true;
   $modal.open({ scope: $scope });
```

Then in your controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    if($scope.inModal) {
       ...
    }
}
```

When you pass $scope to $modal, the $modal will create a child scope that prototypically inherits inModal from the parent scope.  When the controller function is invoked in a normal view, inModal would not be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject it using $inject like this:

```
myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'inModal'];
```

I have done that and it is working fine. below is the code for the $modal.

```
$modal.open({
    controller : "myCtrl",
    resolve: {
        inModal: function() {
            return true;
        }
    }
})
```

controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, inModal) {
    //you can directly use inModal or assign it to $scope property 
});
```

Comment: $injector works only with services - resolve is treated as locals and I cannont inject